# java - How to handle array:Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3

Tags: java

In my code i am comparing the 2 elements of an array. but i got the following exception.please can anybody help me

> array:Exception in thread "main"
>   java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3   at
>   Sarray.main(Sarray.java:64)

```
public class Sarray    
{    
        public static void main(String[] args)  
       {     



     Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in); 
     System.out.print( "Enter sorted array length:" );
     int length = scan.nextInt();

     int[] a = new int[length];
     System.out.println("Enter integer sorted array:");      

     for(int i = 0;i<length;i++) 
     {
         String token = scan.next();
         a[i] = Integer.parseInt(token);         
     }       
     System.out.print("Unique array:");
     int[] b=new int[length];        
     int k=0;
     for(int i=0;i<length;i++)
     {  
        //here i got Exception              
         if(a[i] != a[i+1])
         {
             b[k++]= a[i];
         }
     }               
     for(int i=0;i<k;i++)
     {
         System.out.print(b[i]+" "); 
     }   
 }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 for(int i=0;i<length;i++)
```

should be

```
 for(int i=0;i<length - 1;i++)
```

since you can have `length - 1` number of comparisons.

Answer (score 2):

When `i == length -1` your `i + 1 == length` that is illegal. See `a[i+1]`

Answer (score 1):

Your "i + 1" will go past the array bounds when you reach the last element.

Answer (score -1):

error arrives because value of i+1 is more than the array length.

instead of

```
for (int i=0; i<length; i++)
```

use

```
for (int i=0; i<length-1; i++)
```